# Is there a way to override only delete stored procedure in Entity Framework

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure in my database that I'd like to use for deleting "test" users. I wanted to do this with a stored procedure because of FK constraints that limits doing it through code. So I'm using EF to map to a stored procedure.

The problem I'm running into is that in my logs, I'm seeing tons and tons of errors saying

> cannot find stored procedure user_update/user_insert.

Possibly what Entity Framework does is this that when I use this line of code:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>().MapToStoredProcedures(u => u.Delete(t => t.HasName("UserDelete").Parameter(b => b.ID, "@UserId")));
```

it auto creates or thinks to look for stored procedures in a default manner, as stated above.

I only want to use this for the delete option, so is there a way to make it ignore the update and insert options since I already have methods to take care of that part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately with EF6 you can either use Stored procedures to do **all** update, insert and delete operations or let EF handle queries at run time.

Here's a small hack to help you out:

Add the following line in your code

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .MapToStoredProcedures();
    }
```

This will suggest EF to create Stored procedures using EF convention like

```
 <type_name>_Insert, <type_name>_Update and <type_name>_Delete
```

The above convention is also why you had the error. 
EF expects `User_Insert` and `User_Update` stored procedures.

Now go ahead and replace the EF generated `User_Delete` with your `UserDelete` stored procedure contents.

**PS:** Do not modify parameters of SP. The `User_Delete` expects a parameter and EF will supply them. From EF's documentation:

> The delete stored procedure should have a parameter for the key value
>   of the entity (or multiple parameters if the entity has a composite
>   key). Additionally, the delete procedure should also have parameters
>   for any independent association foreign keys on the target table
>   (relationships that do not have corresponding foreign key properties
>   declared in the entity).